# How to fetch data from model to controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I dont have much knowledge about code igniter and oops.I am working on one form from where i can send data into 2 tables.I did this job of sending data into 2 tables. But before sending data into `second_table` i have to check some conditions from `third_table`. How can i get my `third_table's` data into my controller's function of `insert`. so that i can check my conditions with `if..else` and then only send data into second table.

This is my controller to add data with 2 arrays:`userInfo` and `userInfo1`

```
public function insert()
    {               

        $employee_name = $this->input->post('employee_name');            
        $net_pay = $this->input->post('net_pay');

        $userInfo = array('emp_id'=>$employee_name,                
            'net_pay'=>$net_pay,  
            );

        $data['finance']= $this->Finance_details_model->get_finance();

        if ($data['recursing_type_id'] == 1) 
            {
                $net = $data['ROI']/$net_pay;
            }

        $certificate_no = 'DMFS'.rand(4,9999);

        $userInfo1 = array('user_id'=>$employee_name, 
            'certificate_no' => $certificate_no,
            'amount'=> $net,
            'source_id'=> 2,
            'trans_type_id'=> 1,   
            );

        $this->load->model('Pay_slips_model');
        $result = $this->Pay_slips_model->insert($userInfo,$userInfo1);

        if($result > 0)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'New User created successfully');
            }
        else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User creation failed');
            }
        ob_end_clean();
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');
        $this->load->view('layouts/uk_pdf',TRUE);
        $this->load->library('mpdf');   
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);           
        redirect('responsible/upload_uk_slip');                       

    }
```

As you can see in controller before `$userInfo1` i have call one model

```
$data['finance']= $this->Finance_details_model->get_finance();

        if ($data['recursing_type_id'] == 1) 
            {
                $net = $data['ROI']/$net_pay;
            }
```

In above code I am trying to fetch data from `get_finance`.
`recursing_type_id` and  `ROI` are columns from third table on which i have to set conditions.
Below is my model to get all data from third table.

```
class Finance_details_model extends CI_Model{

    public function get_finance($data)
        {
            $response = array();          
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('finance_user_details');   
            return $response;
        }


    }
```

And this is my model to insert data into 2 tables:

```
public function insert($userInfo,$userInfo1)
            {
                $this->db->trans_start();
                $this->db->insert('uk_new_salary_slip', $userInfo);
                $this->db->insert('finance_transactions', $userInfo1);             
                $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();            
                $this->db->trans_complete();            
                return $insert_id;
            }
```

Comment: In your Insert() Function you are storing emp_id against $this->input->post('employee_name')
Is this correct for you?

Comment: yes its correct bro

Comment: If you are getting more than one row in 
$data['finance']= $this->Finance_details_model->get_finance(); 
use foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

Use this method for getting data

```
class Finance_details_model extends CI_Model{

public function get_finance($data)
    {         

        $query = $this->db->get('finance_user_details');   
        return $query->result(); //OR result_array()
    }


}
```

Comment: looks like he does indeed want an array `$response = array();` maybe make that the first option so as to not confuse ;)

Comment: if($data->num_rows == 1) 
                {
                    foreach ($data->result() as $row)
                    {

                      
                        $data['recursing_type_id'] = $row->recursing_type_id; 
                        $data['ROI'] = $row->ROI;
                   
                    }
                }

Comment: this code in controller and in model as per your code it shows error  Too few arguments to function Finance_details_model::get_finance(),

Comment: only use foreach loop without IF condition